# Weird namespace concept in c++

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

I came across this:

```
template<class T> using PQ = priority_queue<T>;
```

I was not able to understand what is going on so I tried to go to the source code and replicate this myself:

```
template<class T> class I_Love_You {
    public:
    static void print() {
        cout << "Hello StackOverflow!" << endl;
    }
};

template<class F> using We_are_just_friends = I_Love_You<F>;

void solve() {
    We_are_just_friends<int>::print();
}
```

What is going on here? The priority_queue is a template class definition defined in the c++ file which is then linked in c++ at the time of .exe creation.
But what is this using and template and exactly what is going on how I am able to assign template and by using am I creating or defining a namespace? Please can someone break it down for me.

Comment: Which `namespace` are you talking about? The class scope? The alias?

Comment: A `using` in this context is like a (template) `typedef`, nothing related to a namespace.

Comment: OK it's a typedef. I was just confused here. So it's like take everything in priority_queue and alias as PQ right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template<class T> using PQ = priority_queue<T>;
```

`priority_queue` is a templated type, so we always have to specify a type for it.

If we make a alias for it, `PQ`, `priority_queue` still needs to know it's type. So we declare `PQ` a template, and pass the value that is passed to `PQ` to `priority_queue`.

Comment: And, for the bottom like, with this statement added, you can write `priority_queue<int>` or `PQ<int>` and they mean the same thing. Seems like pointless obfuscation. We spend most of our time reading code, not writing it, so code should be written to be easy to read, not easier to write.

Comment: Yes you are right. Writing quality code is more important. It just caught my eye and I couldn't figure it out.